# How many end segments does the axon of a typical cortical pyramidal cell have?

Tags: neuroscience, neuroanatomy

I tried to do some research - starting with a Google search for "typical axonal trees" - and found the following pictures:

[image]

<sub>[source](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233396905_Resolving_the_Detailed_Structure_of_Cortical_and_Thalamic_Neurons_in_the_Adult_Rat_Brain_with_Refined_Biotinylated_Dextran_Amine_Labeling)</sub>

[image]

<sub>[source](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_do_neurons_have_only_one_axon) (axons are red)</sub>

but didn't find a concise answer to this [and](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/66911/how-many-synapses-are-there-in-the-different-target-regions-of-a-typical-cortica) [some](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/66912/how-many-axon-branches-reenter-the-cortex-shortly-after-having-left-the-gray-mat) [related](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/66913/are-there-axon-branches-that-go-up-to-cortex-layer-1-and-spread-there) [questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/66914/are-the-inner-cortical-axon-branches-myelinated):

> How many end segments (which don't branch anymore) does the axon of a typical cortical pyramidal
>   cell typically have. I guess it's a much smaller number than the
>   number of end segments of a typical dendrite, but how large is it
>   roughly: some tens, sometimes less than ten?

I'd like to exclude from this question the typical axonal "end trees" which branch into the axon terminals.

Comment: @vkehayas: I followed your advice.

Comment: Some things to consider: What do you think that this is measure is relevant for? Are you making the implicit assumption that these terminal branches make more synapses? Please edit your question to help us understand what is the underlying question you are trying to answer.

Comment: In my original question - where I asked it all together - I made a distinction: number of synapses = number of end segments times number of synapses (= axon terminals) per end segment. But I am quite sure that not every kind of "end segment" has the same number of synapses (= axon terminals) (not even roughly). This number most probably depends on other things.