# How many synapses are there in the different target regions of a typical cortical pyramidal cell?

Tags: neuroscience, neuroanatomy

I found the following pictures of axon trees:

[image]

<sub>[source](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233396905_Resolving_the_Detailed_Structure_of_Cortical_and_Thalamic_Neurons_in_the_Adult_Rat_Brain_with_Refined_Biotinylated_Dextran_Amine_Labeling)</sub>

[image]

<sub>[source](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_do_neurons_have_only_one_axon) (axons are red)</sub>

but didn't find a concise answer to the following question:

> How many (in relative terms) branches terminate and how many axon
>   terminals (synapses) are there in the different target regions of a
>   typical cortical pyramidal cell, i.e.
>
> - same cortical layer
> - other cortical layers
> - same cortical column
> - other cortical columns
> - more distant cortical regions (e.g. in the same gyrus)
> - subcortical regions

Comment: I take it that you mean how many synapses are formed with a pyramidal neuron and $X$. Talking about branches doesn't make too much sense. You should know that there are 4-7 different types of cortical pyramidal cells, depending on how you count (e.g. [Oberlaender et al. 2012](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3432239/pdf/bhr317.pdf) for the higher estimate). Every single presynaptic source you are asking about is going to have a different estimate for every different type of pyramidal neuron, and some of them are unknown. I'd say this is too broad.

Comment: You "just" say there is no typical pyramidal neuron? I know that

Comment: ... but 4-7 is not such a big number one couldn't give a partial answer: for type X it is so-and-so, ... Should I rephrase my question? To which of the 4-7 types would you recommend to restrict my question?

Comment: I'd say we only have numbers for the number of synapses or the volume of axon that comes or goes inside or outside the column, with no estimates about specific neurons, but I really do hope that someone will prove me wrong.